# Count and sum column list

Tags: awk

Not 100% sure how to do this.  What I have does not add up.

```
awk -F, '{array[$1]+=$2} END { for (i in array) {print i array[i] }}' gaaa
```

Here is a example of gaaa

```
acic 4
acgic 56
acpdc 183
acic 1677
acpicvp 
acsis 23
hidr 4
hidr 1133
aggr 24
```

Desired result would be:

```
acic 1681
acgic 56
acpdc 183
acpicvp 
acsis 23
hidr 1137
aggr 24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the field separator to a comma but there is no comma in your data. You want:

```
$ awk '{array[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in array) print i,array[i]}' gaaa
acsis 23
aggr 24
acgic 56
acpdc 183
hidr 1137
acpicvp 0
acic 1681
```